# Gcloud logs viewer - search for substring filter not working

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, log-viewer

According to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries#searching_examples), using `:"string"` on a field searches for the substring.

But it's not working, there is no result. Here is the filter I use in the https://console.cloud.google.com/logs

```
resource.type="k8s_container"
resource.labels.namespace_name="default"
resource.labels.container_name="product"
jsonPayload.MESSAGE:"video"
```

Is there something wrong in the way I am doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `jsonPayload.message` instead, UI insists on providing completion for MESSAGE which does not exist in this context.